# Results Coming Back For Each Row

Tags: php, mysql

```
$friendship = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE accountid='$row[id]' && status='approved'") or trigger_error(mysql_error());  
while($joysong2 = mysql_fetch_array($friendship))
{
    $newnot=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifyme where userid='$joysong2[friendid]' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 0,5") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
    while($notify = mysql_fetch_array($newnot))
    {

 }
}
```

Hi guys let me explain what I am trying to do here.

My $friendship query is giving us back a result of the users who the user has approved to communicate with.

So the result would come back as 1,3,4,5 depending on the other users user id.

The second query $newnot is using the information $friendship and bringing back 5 entries in the table notifyme.

Problem is right now that I'm getting 5 results for each user.

What I wanted was only 5 results in total from notify me in date/time order.

eg.

```
1 posted 1/08/2015
1 posted 2/08/2015
3 posted 1/08/2015
4 posted 2/08/2015
3 posted 3/08/2015
```

I would want them back as

```
3 posted 3/08/2015
4 posted 2/08/2015
1 posted 2/08/2015
3 posted 1/08/2015
1 posted 1/08/2015
```

right now though my results are coming back as

```
1 posted 1/08/2015
1 posted 2/08/2015
1 posted 1/07/2015
1 posted 1/06/2015
1 posted 1/05/2015

3 posted 3/08/2015
3 posted 1/08/2015
3 posted 1/07/2015
3 posted 1/06/2015
3 posted 1/05/2015
```

I guess you get what I mean. So how do I get this to work?

Comment: if my explaining is terrible I will try to help clear up what I mean

Comment: Why not make a single query that both finds who the user is approved to communicate with, then brings back the desired values? It's definitely going to be more efficient to make one query than to hit the DB multiple times.

Comment: Do you want number of posts for each day, per user?

Comment: Wouldn't that just do the same though, from it knowing the users that the user can communicate with, it would drag back 5 results for each user. That would be something I am trying not to do, I would want just 5 results in total from all the users regardless if user 1 posted 20 times or 3 posted 50 times, all I would want to see on the page is 5

Comment: nope notify me would have say 1000 posts in it from all users on the database. What I am trying to do is, only have 5 results in total (not for each user) from notify me where the userid matches the relationship in friends, right now this gives me 5 results for each relationship in friends.

Comment: This right now causes a problem as say if you had 10 relationships in friends it would mean my page will display 50 results as it would do 5 results from each relationship. In fact all I want is my page to show 5 results only. This is why I am ordering by date and time so the results would be mixed between the relationship.

Comment: What do you mean: 'relationship'?

Comment: $friendship is the relationship query. it is finding out who lets call them user 0 has an approved friendship with.

Comment: Do you want a list of number of posts for the last 5 days for users who are related (friends) with user 0 no matter who is the user?

Comment: correct. Which it is currently doing but it is doing it for each user who are related to user 0. eg. 10 related users = 5 results per user = 50 results in total. I need to minimise this to just be 5 results in total in date order.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this will help you better, but consider some error because I didn't test it. You are welcome to show errors until we fix it. replace some column names with the one you use:

```
SELECT accountid, status, cnt_rows, `date` FROM friends f

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt_rows, `date`, f_id FROM notifyme n) AS n_cnt
  ON f.id=n_cnt.f_id
)
GROUP BY n_cnt.date
WHERE status='approved'
OREDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I'm not sure, or I cant get my head around how this would work as my original post showed that $friendship looked to see if user 0 had any "approved" relationships from the 'status' column where 'accountid' contains user 0. And then my query in $newnot looked for any posts from the users who had a relationship with user 0

Comment: I updated the answer with: 'WHERE status='approved'. Is that enough to check for approved users?

Comment: would have to be where status='approved' && accountid='$row[id]'. I do not have a date column in FRIENDS though all I have is ID, ACCOUNTID, FRIENDID, STATUS. Finally would NOTIFYME know to only look for results where USERID would is only the results of the first paragraph statement?

Comment: 1. The date is taked from notifymy table. 2. I think You can use JOIN instead of PHP looping functions like WHILE. I hope this helps you somehow.